# QueryDSL/JPAExpressions causing duplicate join statements in subquery

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, querydsl

We're using spring and querying via querydsl/jpaexpressions. I noticed when using a subquery with joins, it duplicates the joins resulting in perf issues. For example,

```
select
    *
from
    foo
where
    foo.id in (
    select
        bar.id
    from
        bar
    join alpha on
        bar.field = alpha.field)
```

was resulting in

```
select
    *
from
    foo
where
    foo.id in (
    select
        bar.id
    from
        bar b,
        alpha a,
        bar b1,
        alpha a1)
```

Has anyone experienced issues with this? I'm using JPAexpressions to generate my subquery

```
JPAExpressions.select(....)
```

Comment: **(1)** `exists (select * from bar where bar.id = foo.id ...` was advocated to be better optimizable as opposed to `foo.id in (select`. **(2)** Should `join` not be a `where bar.field = alpha.field`? This join query looks explosive.

Comment: I'm not a sql expert by any means. But isn't the join needed to reference an equality statement between entities?

Comment: No, if you got a headers table and a 1:N lines table, you _join_ them on the header ID. In effect multiplying every header record by its lines. That is the effect you saw. A _join_ is like a `from table1, table2 where table2.id = table1.table2_id`. Do some SQL tutorials, will be helpful, also with JPA.